# Conflict in type inflection between EmberData and Django REST framework

Tags: django, ember-data, django-rest-framework, json-api

`EmberData` is `POST`ing:

```
{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "name": "The project name",
      "description": "The project description",
      "price": 123
    },
    "relationships": {
      "onwer": {
        "data": null
      }
    },
    "type": "projects"
  }
}
```

And `Django` (`drf` I guess) is complaining with a `409 Conflict`:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "detail": "The resource object's type (projects) is not the type that constitute the collection represented by the endpoint (project)."
  }
}
```

Apparently the `JSONApi` spec [does not](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-identification) enforce an inflection rule. How can I tell `drf` to accept plurals for the type?

Comment: If your model is of the type `project`, shouldn't you be submitting this from Ember? You are not creating a `Projects` model instance, you are creating a `Project`.

Comment: @Ashley'CptLemming'Wilson: As said, JSONApi does not specify this - it is an implementation decision. Both ways are accepted, and the EmberData way and the Django way are in conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [config parameter](http://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#relationship-types):

```
JSON_API_PLURALIZE_RELATION_TYPE = True
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also explicitly set the resource name:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    resource_name = 'categories'
    ...
```